# Pipe materials by percent of total length and length in miles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, attribute-table

I am filling out a survey that asks questions about our water mains such as total miles in our system. This was easy to figure out with the length field. The next question asks "What is the distribution of the total miles that uses certain materials such as Cast Iron, HDPE, PVC etc.. We do have a material field in our water mains layers. How could I break this down to come up with the percent of Total Length and Length in miles for each individual pipe material. I have tried using the summarize tool and calculate field but I can't seem to come up with any numbers that seem to be close.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Split By Attributes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/split-by-attributes.htm) tool to split your water mains by material type. Then [Dissolve](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) each resulting feature class by material type. This should give you a feature class for each material type, each with 1 line feature. You can then add a field to each feature class to calculate the percentage(or do this by hand). You will divide the length of the individual feature class by the length of your total water main network.

Answer (score 0):

I filled out a similar survey for our Water Main materials. I just exported the Water Main table to an excel spreadsheet and used SUMIFS to sum up lengths based on the material that was present. You could also probably just use summary statistics and set it with Case Field as material. Hope this helps!